# See who saved each version in excel

Tags: excel, version

Good day,

I need to find out who saved each version of an excel file. I have the previous versions and when they were created yet do not know how to find out who saved it. 
The situation cocerns the last 2 versions. 2 versions ago, i saves the file. I know for sure that the last save was done by someone else, yet in the last saved by, i am the one displayed. Please help!

Best regards,
Vlad C.

Comment: The "Last saved by" field in File->properties->statistics should show you who last saved.  Is that where you are looking?

Comment: My name is written there. Although I am surely not the one who did the modifications to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can enable track changes on the workbook, which will show the specific areas of the workbook that were changed each time.

Comment: Unfortunately it was not active. Didn't expect anyone to mess around with my files... I will activate it from now on though..

Comment: Ah. That's usually a good way of handling things that you need to track changes on. :)  (Also, if the file was on Sharepoint or Dropbox or another file sharing system - possibly even the company server - you can go through and figure out the log of who's made changes. Often you have to contact IT, but if it's a concern, they can usually dredge it up.)